# A basic proof on Morse Function

Tags: differential-topology

The questions is to show if $f_t$ is a homotopic family of functions on $R^k$, show that if $f_0$ is Morse in some neighborhood of a compact set $K$, then so is every $f_t$ for sufficiently small t.

I get the previous question leads to the proof, but couldn't reach the question:

det$(H)^2 + \sum_{i=1}^k (\partial f/ \partial x_i)^2 > 0$

And also, on a compact manifold:

det$(H)^2 + \sum_{i=1}^k (\partial f/ \partial x_i)^2 >\epsilon$

Thanks for your help!

Comment: What is $H$?  What is $\epsilon$?  Can you provide a little more context, please?

Comment: @JesseMadnick Dear Jesse, Thank you so much! H is the Hessian Matrix, and $\epsilon$ just means an arbitrarily small positive number. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

G&P have you prove that the first inequality is equivalent to $f$ Morse. If the quantity is $>\epsilon$ for $f_0$, then by smoothness, for small enough $t$ it'll be $>\epsilon/2$ for $f_t$.

Comment: Thank you Ted. I don't understand why it'll be $>\epsilon/2$ for $f_t$. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: What fundamental facts do you know about continuous functions?

Comment: Continuous function has max/min on a compact set?

Comment: And how does that minimum value vary if you wiggle $t$?

Comment: If $t$ is wiggled, $H_t$ and $\partial f_t/ \partial x_i$ change. So I get confused.

Comment: What's the definition of continuity in your topology courses?

Comment: A function f : X→ Y between topological spaces is called continuous if for all x ∈ X and all neighbourhoods N of f(x) there is a neighbourhood M of x such that f(M) ⊆ N.

Comment: OK, you need to think now about how this all fits together. I've given enough hints. Where are you a student?

Comment: Thanks - let me sleep with it and see if I can figure it out.

Comment: Oh - I just graduated this year. =)

Comment: So where are you studying differential topology? A key tool throughout this course (and elsewhere in mathematics) is the so-called Tube Lemma: If $X$ is compact and $U$ is a neighborhood of $X\times \{y_0\}$ in $X\times Y$, then $U$ contains a "tube" $X\times V$, for some neighborhood $V$ of $y_0$ in $Y$.

Comment: Hi Ted, thanks for inform me that! I am reading GP by myself. :-)